# Вопрос по архитектуре нейронной сети(многослойного перцептрона)

Tags: архитектура, нейронные-сети

Я пишу нейронную сеть, которая должна аппроксимировать некую гладкую функцию(sin(x), к примеру).
Архитектура такая - `(один вход):(3 скрытых слоя по 5 нейронов):(1 выход)`.
Обучаю сеть с помощью обратного распространения ошибки.

Сейчас воткнулся в проблему, решения которой в литературе не нашел.
У меня на всех нейронах функция активации - биполярный сигмоид с областью значений (-1;1). Очевидно, что на выходе тогда тоже будут значения (-1;1). А это означает, что будут заведомо неверные ответы.

Объясните, пожалуйста, что делать в таком случае.

UPD: Нагуглил немного - пишут, что нужно пре- и постпроцессирование информации. То есть, насколько я понял, надо как-то подгонять входные данные, чтобы они подходили каким-то образом под область чувствительности активационной функции. А потом на выходе "конвертировать" их обратно.
Но, опять же, я не очень понимаю как. Получить "хорошие" значения, преобразуя числа из промежутка (-1;1), когда аппроксимируемая функция нелинейная - отнюдь не тривиальная задача.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Привожу перевод фрагмента статьи https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/07/01/neural-network-data-normalization-and-encoding.aspx

**Нормализация числовых данных**

Есть два вида нейросетевых числовых данных: *независимые (х) числовые данные* и *зависимые (у) числовые данные*. Примером *независимых числовых данных* может служить `возраст` (54, 28, 31, 48, 22, 39).

Я рекомендую **нормализацию** *независимых числовых данных* путем вычисления
`среднего арифметического` (**mean**) и `среднеквадратическое отклонения` (**standard deviation**, **stddev**) числовых данных, а затем применять преобразование **(х - mean) / stddev** <sup>*1)</sup>.

Например, `среднее арифметическое` из всех шести значений `возраста` является **37.0** и `стандартное отклонение` шести значений `возраста` является **11,22**. Таким образом, нормализацией `возраста` для первого лица является **(54,0 - 37,0) / 11,22 = 1,51**.

В большинстве случаев, нормированные числовые данные будут иметь значения, которые варьируются между -6.0 и +6,0. Идея нормализации данных заключается в масштабировании всех числовых данных, так что они будут иметь приблизительно одинаковые величины.

Например, типичный `годовой доход` составляет **30,000**, а типичное значение `возраста` составляет **31,0**. Без нормализации, большие величины данных относительно `дохода` к данным `возраста` сделали бы процесс обучения *НС* гораздо сложнее, чем с нормированными данными, так как изменения `подоходных` весов будет иметь гораздо больший эффект, чем изменения в `возрастных` весов.

Для зависимых числовых данных, за исключением очень необычных случаев, я рекомендую не нормализовать и не преобразовывать данные.

<sup>*)</sup>
**Стандартное отклонение в полном наборе данных**

Чтобы вычислить отклонение, выполните следующие действия:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Выработайте *Среднее* (простое *среднее арифметическое*).
2. Затем для каждого числа: вычтите *Среднее* значение и
   возведите результат в квадрат (квадрат разности).
3. Затем выработайте *среднее* значение этих квадратов.
4. Вычислите квадратный корень *среднего* значения.