# Корректная нормализация входных данных в нейронных сетях

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, нормализация-данных

Есть функция , которая делает нормализацию данных :

```
def normalize_values(iqValue,funValue,montageValue):
    iqValueM = [iqValue]
    funValueM = [funValue]
    montageValueM = [montageValue]

    iqValue      = (iqValueM[0] - reduce(max,iqValueM)) / (reduce(max,iqValueM) - reduce(min,iqValueM))
    funValue     = (funValueM[0] - reduce(max,funValueM)) / (reduce(max,funValueM) - reduce(min,funValueM))
    montageValue = (montageValueM[0] - reduce(max,montageValueM)) / (reduce(max,montageValueM) - reduce(min,montageValueM))

    return iqValue,funValue,montageValue
```

Я знаю что будет ошибка `DivisionByZero` , но нормализацию данных я делал по формуле  `norm = (input - min) / (max - min)` . **Как** правильно нормализовать данные в нейронных сетях ?

Comment: Привожу ссылку на мой ответ на похожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/523343/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%85%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0/570504#570504

Comment: @AntonDanilov Спасибо за ссылку , помогла.как узнать среднее отклонение если к пример iq = 140 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Привожу ссылку на мой ответ на похожий вопрос:

[Вопрос по архитектуре нейронной сети(многослойного перцептрона)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/523343/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%85%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0/570504#570504/523343/)…

**Стандартное отклонение** в полном наборе данных

[image: Стандартное отклонение в полном наборе данных]

Чтобы вычислить отклонение, выполните следующие действия:

1. Выработайте **Среднее** (простое среднее арифметическое).
2. Затем для каждого числа: вычесть Среднее значение и возвести результат  в квадрат (квадрат разности).
3. Затем выработайте среднее значение этих квадратов.
4. Вычислите  кв. корень  среднего значения.

**Стандартное отклонение** в выборке

[image: Стандартное отклонение в выборке:]
Важным изменением является «N-1» вместо «N» (которое называется «коррекция Бесселя»).

Символы также меняются, чтобы отразить то, что мы работаем над выборкой вместо полного набора данных:

Среднее значение теперь **x** (для среднего значения выборки) вместо **μ** (среднее значение полного набора данных), И ответ - **s** (для стандартного отклонения выборки) вместо **σ**.

ссылка:

https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-deviation.html

Comment: Попробовал , но если числа сильно отличаются , то даже после нормализации данных будут отличатся сильно . К примеру массив данных = [30000,6,8] , то разница между полученными не маленькая.

Comment: @True-hacker Разумеется, когда раэброс данных такой :) 30000 -:- 6,8. ЭТО РЕАЛЬНЫЙ ПРИМЕР?

Comment: Это не реальный пример , я просто тестировал как работает нормализация данных :))